# Is there a way to make a spring data jpa query in order to see if a string contains any other string in a list?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

So im doing a project where we have a "topics" mechanic, actually very similar to stack overflow's one.
So im saving each entity (cooking recipe) a topics variable that contains a comma separated string. Now my big problem here is i need to findByTopics, as in multiple topics. Ive tried the @Query

```
@Query("select new com.fullstack.dtos.projections.LocalizedRecipe(t.id, t.created, t.createdBy, t.lastModified, t.lastModifiedBy, t.version, l.title, l.description) from tutorial t inner join t.localizations l where l.id.locale = :lang and t.topics in :topics")
Page<LocalizedRecipe> findAllByTopics(String lang, Set<String> topics, Pageable page);
```

I have even changed my model so that topics are an @ElementCollection of Strings trying to use the same query but there are always type errors. Most of the time it throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Java] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)]
```

My question here is how do i do so that this works. Changing my model isn't a problem, i just can't seem to find a good way to do it.

Current model:

```
public class RecipeDAO {

@Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2", strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", unique = true)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private UUID id;

    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime lastModified;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    private Boolean visible;

    private String topics;

    @MapKey(name = "id.locale")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipe", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Map<String, Localization> localizations;
}
```

My end goal here is be able to check if, let's say there are 3 recipes with the topics "breakfast, lunch, dinner". I want to be able to findByTopics with ["lunch", "dinner"] and it returns those, returns all that have dinner or lunch in the topics string
Basically a substring matcher. Or an alternative to achieve this, as i said changing the model isn't a problem

EDIT: I've also tried changing to List and become an @ElementCollection but there comes an error. I dont know if i can see if the two lists intersect.

Comment: First thing your current model is not clear from question.
Please share that.

Comment: Also please share repository method and what is the parameter you are passing to filter ?
Is it a string or list?

Comment: I've edited to include the current model.

Comment: Its a set, could be a list if needed or even a java array/varargs. My issue is how to do the query. I want to see if the "topics" parameter of the object has any of the strings in the set.

Comment: You can check https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-query-elementcollection/
and also as suggested by others using method names should also work

Answer (score 0):

1. In repository you can use derived query method, where each **parameter** referring the **properties** of the respective entity - for example

   findByTopicsOrTopics(String topic1, String topic2);

corresponding sql query -

```
select * from RecipeDAO where topics="topic1" OR topics="topic2";
```

2. If the number of Topics are more, then using the **collection of topics** as parameter in method is better choice than passing the *each topics as a separate parameter*.

Supplying **Collection of topics against using In**

```
List<RecipeDAO> findByTopicsIn(Collection<String> topics);
```

Corresponding sql query -

```
select * from RecipeDAO where topics in('topics1','topics2',...,'topicsn');
```

Comment: Im aware, but i dont know how many topics are coming. Could be 1 could be 2 could be 10

Comment: Then you can use the derived queriy method  by supplying Collection of  topics against using In `List<RecipeDAO> findByTopicsIn(Collection<String> topics);`

Comment: Would that work in my example? I would need to change topics to a string @ElementCollection correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with the `In` keyword as follows:

```java
findByTopicsIn(Collection<String> topics)
```